# Compressing only the files inside a given directory using tarfile (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, filesystems, compression, tar

I have written the following script that allows me to compress a `src` (which can be either a single file or a directory) to target 'dst':

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import tarfile
from ntpath import basename, dirname
from os import path, listdir, makedirs, chdir
import errno
import sys

class Archivator:
    @staticmethod
    def compress(src='input/test', dst='output'):
        # if not path.isfile(src_file):
        #     print('Expecting absolute path to file (not directory) as "src". If "src" does contain a file, the file does not exist')
        #     return False

        if not path.isdir(dst):
            return False
            # try:
            #     makedirs(dst_dir)
            # except OSError as err:
            #     if err.errno != errno.EEXIST:
            #         return False

        filename = basename(src) if path.isdir(src) else src
        tar_file = dst + '/' + filename + '.tar.gz'
        print(tar_file)
        print(src)
        with tarfile.open(tar_file, 'w:gz') as tar:
            print('Creating archive "' + tar_file + '"')
            # chdir(dirname(dst_dir))
            recr = path.isdir(src)
            if recr:
                print('Source is a directory. Will compress all contents using recursion')
            tar.add(src, recursive=recr)

        return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import argparse

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Uses tar to compress file')
    parser.add_argument('-src', '--source', type=str,
                        help='Absolute path to file (not directory) that will be compressed')
    parser.add_argument('-dst', '--destination', type=str, default='output/',
                        help='Path to output directory. Create archive inside the directory will have the same name as value of "--src" argument')

    # Generate configuration
    config = parser.parse_args()

    Archivator.compress(config.source, config.destination)
```

For single files I haven't had an issue so far. However while the compression of `src` (as a directory) does worked (recursion and all) I have noticed a very annoying issue namely that the complete directory structure is replicated inside the `tar.gz` archive.

Example:

Let's say I have the following file structure:

```
./
 |---compression.py (script above)
 |
 |---updates/
 |       |
 |       |---package1/
 |               |
 |               |---file1
 |               |---file2
 |               |---dir/
 |                     |
 |                     |---file3
 |
 |---compressed/
```

with `src = 'updates/package1'` and `dst = 'compressed'` I am expecting that the resulting archive will

- be placed inside `dst` (this works)
- contain `file1` and `file2`

About the second point I expect

```
./
 |---compression.py (script above)
 |
 |---updates/
 |       |
 |       |---package1/
 |               |
 |               |---file1
 |               |---file2
 |               |---dir/
 |                    |
 |                    |---file3
 |
 |---compressed/
          |
          |---package1.tar.gz
                 |
                 |---file1
                 |---file2
                 |---dir/
                      |
                      |---file3
```

but instead I get

```
./
 |---compression.py (script above)
 |
 |---updates/
 |       |
 |       |---package1/
 |               |
 |               |---file1
 |               |---file2
 |               |---dir/
 |                    |
 |                    |---file3
 |
 |---compressed/
         |
         |---package1.tar.gz
                 |
                 |---updates/
                        |
                        |---package1/
                                |
                                |---file1
                                |---file2
                                |---dir/
                                     |
                                     |---file3
```

While the solution might be really trivial I seem to not be able to figure it out. I even tried `chdir`-ing inside the `src` (if a directory) but it didn't work. Some of my experiments even led to `OSError` (due to missing directory where it was expected to be present) and a corrupted archive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are using parameter `recursive` wrongly.

According to the official document of `tarfile`:

```
def add(self, name, arcname=None, recursive=True, exclude=None):
    """Add the file `name' to the archive. `name' may be any type of file
       (directory, fifo, symbolic link, etc.). If given, `arcname'
       specifies an alternative name for the file in the archive.
       Directories are added recursively by default. This can be avoided by
       setting `recursive' to False. `exclude' is a function that should
       return True for each filename to be excluded.
    """
```

You can use `arcname` to specify the alternative name in the archive. And `recursive` is used to control if creates directories recursively.

`tarfile` can directly add a directory.

Back to your question, you can manually add each files and specify their `arcname`. For example, `tar.add("updates/package1/file1", "file1")`.

### update

Or you can set `arcname` to an empty string. As it will omit the root directory.

Comment: I actually have directories inside `package1`. The `file1` and `file2` were just an example.

Comment: Ah, your explanation gave an idea to experiment with `arcname`. If you set `arcname=''` (empty string) it does exactly what I want! Please edit your answer so that I can mark it as the correct one. :)

Comment: OK, now I understand you completely. First I thought you want to flatten all files...

Comment: Nope, I just wanted to remove all directories above and including `package1`. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I basically used `.replace` to remove the base folder path with `arcname`.

```
        with tarfile.open(tar_path, tar_compression) as tar_handle:
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(test_data_path):
                for file in files:
                    tar_handle.add(os.path.join(root, file), arcname=os.path.join(root, file).replace(test_data_path, ""))
```